# Create a function handle within a structure, given some coefficients

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of coefficients available, which are the coefficients of an interpolating polynomial. I want to create a field in a structure as follows:

```
p.val =@(y) polynomial
```

Here polynomial is the polynomial with my coefficients in the indeterminate `y`. I'm not sure how to do this. The field has to contain a function handle like this.

The user has to be able to call this as follows:

```
pval = p.val(y)
```

where, `y` can be a vector of any length, supplied by the user (which contains values where the polynomial needs to be evaluated). So, this output has to be a column vector, such that every cell contains the specific function value.

Any help on how this can be done is appreciated!

Comment: Forget the anonymous function for now.  First figure out what the code needs to be to evaluate the polynomial, first for a single point, then for multiple points.  Then you just put that code in the body of the anonymous function, like this;  `@(y) code_that_computes_output_as_a_function_of_y_and_polynomial`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what function you want to implement, but the length of the vector you are including does not matter.

example.a = 3; % Any variable
example.b = @(s) mean(s);

The function mean here can be anything from a built-in function to a custom function you just made.

You can call it by:
result = example.b(rand(1000,1);

Comment: That Won't work. I need to make a polynomial from the coefficients I have. This polynomial (in the variable y) i need to put in the field as: p.val = @(y) polynomial. If I use the built-in function 'poly2sym' then I won't be able to evaluate my function anymore. It has to be called as pval = p.val(y). So it has to be evaluated in the vector y.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need. Can you exemplify what polynomial is? Just write down some pseudocode, so that we can understand what you are after.